# I want to host a wcf web service created in vb.Net on Microsoft azure

Tags: azure

I have a web service, created in VB.Net and I want to host that webservice on Microsoft Azure. Can anyone help me ?
I am new to Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least a few options here:

1. The most straightforward and old school - create a VM and host it as you would on a local server.
2. Create a Cloud Service which is somewhat easier and you get scalability and disaster recovery out of the box, which requires a bit of learning path on Azure SDK.
3. Invest in Service Fabric and host it as a Reliable Stateful Service - again it's a learning path, however you are winning here in terms that this is the technology to go forward, whereas option 2 will get deprecated fairly soon.